Performance issues using CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR
I am running into performance issues using CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR in my query.
What I am trying to do is given a CUST_NUM, identify all CUST_ID's associated with it and all CUST_NUM for those, and so on...
Below is the query I am running but having performance issues with it on a large database with 2M+ rows.
Any help is much appreciated and if you could explain what am I doing wrong
SELECT DISTINCT CUST_NUM, CUST_ID, TIER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE
FROM TABLE1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR UPPER(CUST_NUM)=UPPER(CUST_NUM)
  OR PRIOR UPPER(CUST_ID)=UPPER(CUST_ID)
START WITH UPPER(CUST_NUM) = UPPER('2987530')
ORDER BY CUST_NUM, STARTDATE;

**Below is the test data:
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
CUST_NUM VARCHAR2 (10),
CUST_ID VARCHAR2 (20),
TIER VARCHAR2 (10),
STARTDATE TIMESTAMP (0),
ENDDATE TIMESTAMP (0) ) ;

Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2819579', 'P000000000001924474', 'TIER_A', '2015-09-24 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2819579', 'P000000000001924474', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-01-29 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2819579', 'P000000000001924474', 'TIER_C', '2019-01-29 00:00:00', '2021-04-13 11:15:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2819579', 'P000000000001763124', 'TIER_C', '2022-03-17 11:00:00', '2022-09-14 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987530', 'P000000000002057322', 'TIER_A', '2016-05-14 00:00:00', '2016-07-15 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987530', 'P000000000001634343', 'TIER_A', '2017-03-24 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987530', 'P000000000001634343', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-14 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987530', 'P000000000001634343', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-14 00:00:00', '2021-06-16 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987530', 'P000000000001711763', 'TIER_C', '2022-02-07 12:45:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987541', 'P000000000001968900', 'TIER_A', '2016-04-30 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987541', 'P000000000001968900', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-04 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987541', 'P000000000001968900', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-04 00:00:00', '2024-01-31 09:45:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987508', 'P000000000001705747', 'TIER_A', '2016-04-16 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987508', 'P000000000001705747', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-04 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987508', 'P000000000001705747', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-04 00:00:00', '2022-01-26 10:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987572', 'P000000000002023008', 'TIER_A', '2016-10-06 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987572', 'P000000000002023008', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-25 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987572', 'P000000000002023008', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-25 00:00:00', '2019-10-18 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987572', 'P000000000001832530', 'TIER_C', '2021-01-13 09:30:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987581', 'P000000000001866100', 'TIER_A', '2016-12-13 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987581', 'P000000000001866100', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-16 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987581', 'P000000000001866100', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-16 00:00:00', '2023-12-13 10:45:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987595', 'P000000000002023001', 'TIER_A', '2016-08-27 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987595', 'P000000000002023001', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-01-31 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987595', 'P000000000002023001', 'TIER_C', '2019-01-31 00:00:00', '2023-11-20 11:45:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987595', 'P000000000001968900', 'TIER_C', '2024-01-31 09:45:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987637', 'P000000000001745445', 'TIER_A', '2017-04-17 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987637', 'P000000000001745445', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-23 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987637', 'P000000000001745445', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-23 00:00:00', '2023-11-01 13:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987637', 'P000000000002023001', 'TIER_C', '2023-11-20 11:45:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2880699', 'P000000000002057322', 'TIER_A', '2016-07-15 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2880699', 'P000000000002057322', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-11 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2880699', 'P000000000002057322', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-11 00:00:00', '2021-02-05 11:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2880699', 'P000000000001696121', 'TIER_C', '2021-04-02 11:45:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535914', 'P000000000001711763', 'TIER_A', '2016-09-17 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535914', 'P000000000001711763', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-23 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535914', 'P000000000001711763', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-23 00:00:00', '2022-02-07 12:45:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535914', 'P000000000001743922', 'TIER_C', '2022-10-26 09:45:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535924', 'P000000000001743922', 'TIER_A', '2016-11-19 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535924', 'P000000000001743922', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-01-30 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535924', 'P000000000001743922', 'TIER_C', '2019-01-30 00:00:00', '2020-08-17 14:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535924', 'P000000000001705747', 'TIER_C', '2022-01-26 10:00:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535890', 'P000000000002035081', 'TIER_A', '2016-11-19 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535890', 'P000000000002035081', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-19 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535890', 'P000000000002035081', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-19 00:00:00', '2022-05-20 13:30:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3535890', 'P000000000001725058', 'TIER_C', '2023-11-02 14:30:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3136624', 'P000000000001832530', 'TIER_A', '2016-02-13 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3136624', 'P000000000001832530', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-14 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3136624', 'P000000000001832530', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-14 00:00:00', '2021-01-13 09:30:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3136624', 'P000000000001743922', 'TIER_C', '2021-10-05 00:00:00', '2022-10-26 09:45:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3136624', 'P000000000004969578', 'TIER_C', '2023-11-02 10:15:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987781', 'P000000000001763124', 'TIER_A', '2016-10-29 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987781', 'P000000000001763124', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-17 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987781', 'P000000000001763124', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-17 00:00:00', '2022-03-07 11:15:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('2987781', 'P000000000001722432', 'TIER_C', '2022-05-04 14:15:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3754236', 'P000000000004969578', 'TIER_A', '2017-05-15 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3754236', 'P000000000004969578', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-13 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3754236', 'P000000000004969578', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-13 00:00:00', '2023-11-02 10:15:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3754269', 'P000000000001722432', 'TIER_A', '2017-09-16 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3754269', 'P000000000001722432', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-11 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3754269', 'P000000000001722432', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-11 00:00:00', '2022-04-04 13:45:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3754269', 'P000000000002035081', 'TIER_C', '2022-05-20 13:30:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3011204', 'P000000000001696121', 'TIER_A', '2016-02-02 00:00:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3011204', 'P000000000001696121', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-01-30 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3011204', 'P000000000001696121', 'TIER_C', '2019-01-30 00:00:00', '2021-04-02 11:45:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3011204', 'P000000000001763124', 'TIER_C', '2022-03-07 11:15:00', '2022-03-17 11:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3011204', 'P000000000001866100', 'TIER_C', '2023-12-13 10:45:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3910132', 'P000000000001656589', 'TIER_A', '2018-03-19 13:15:00', '2018-06-20 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3910132', 'P000000000001656589', 'TIER_B', '2018-06-20 00:00:00', '2019-02-16 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3910132', 'P000000000001656589', 'TIER_C', '2019-02-16 00:00:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3910271', 'P000000000002057322', 'TIER_C', '2021-02-05 11:00:00', '2022-07-06 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3940456', 'P000000000001924474', 'TIER_C', '2021-04-13 11:15:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3816264', 'P000000000001743922', 'TIER_C', '2020-08-17 14:00:00', '2021-10-05 00:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3820058', 'P000000000001656589', 'TIER_A', '2017-02-17 00:00:00', '2018-03-19 13:15:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3820058', 'P000000000001722432', 'TIER_C', '2022-04-04 13:45:00', '2022-05-04 14:15:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('3820058', 'P000000000001745445', 'TIER_C', '2023-11-01 13:00:00', '2030-12-31 19:00:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('1111111', 'P000000000001111111', 'TIER_A', '2017-02-17 00:00:00', '2018-03-19 13:15:00');
Insert into TABLE1(CUST_NUM,CUST_ID,TIER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) values ('1111111', 'P000000000001111111', 'TIER_C', '2022-04-04 13:45:00', '2022-05-04 14:15:00');




SELECT DISTINCT CUST_NUM, CUST_ID, TIER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE
FROM TABLE1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR UPPER(CUST_NUM)=UPPER(CUST_NUM)
  OR PRIOR UPPER(CUST_ID)=UPPER(CUST_ID)
START WITH UPPER(CUST_NUM) = UPPER('2987530')
ORDER BY CUST_NUM, STARTDATE;


Please properly format your sample data. You can find formatting help for tables by clicking the ? button on the editor toolbar when you [edit] your post. You should also read Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question before making that edit.

Sorry, had to reformat the test data. The test data is particularly long to highlight the relationship w.r.t. timeline

CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
   PRIOR UPPER(CUST_NUM)=UPPER(CUST_NUM)
OR PRIOR UPPER(CUST_ID)=UPPER(CUST_ID)

This will create a hierarchy, if you have the sample data:
INSERT INTO table1 (cust_num, cust_id, tier, startdate, enddate)
SELECT '1', 'A', 'X', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1', 'B', 'Y', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1', 'C', 'Z', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'C', 'X', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'D', 'Y', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'E', 'Z', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL;

And start with CUST_NUM=1 then you can see the paths generated using the query:
SELECT CUST_NUM,
       CUST_ID,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH('('||cust_num||','||cust_id||')', '->') AS path
FROM   TABLE1
START WITH
       UPPER(CUST_NUM) = '1'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR UPPER(CUST_NUM)=UPPER(CUST_NUM)
OR     PRIOR UPPER(CUST_ID)=UPPER(CUST_ID);

Which outputs:



CUST_NUM
CUST_ID
PATH




1
A
->(1,A)


1
B
->(1,A)->(1,B)


1
C
->(1,A)->(1,B)->(1,C)


2
C
->(1,A)->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)


2
D
->(1,A)->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)


2
E
->(1,A)->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)->(2,E)


2
E
->(1,A)->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)


2
D
->(1,A)->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)->(2,D)


1
C
->(1,A)->(1,C)


1
B
->(1,A)->(1,C)->(1,B)


2
C
->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)


2
D
->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)


2
E
->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)->(2,E)


2
E
->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)


2
D
->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)->(2,D)


1
B
->(1,B)


1
A
->(1,B)->(1,A)


1
C
->(1,B)->(1,A)->(1,C)


2
C
->(1,B)->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)


2
D
->(1,B)->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)


2
E
->(1,B)->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)->(2,E)


2
E
->(1,B)->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)


2
D
->(1,B)->(1,A)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)->(2,D)


1
C
->(1,B)->(1,C)


1
A
->(1,B)->(1,C)->(1,A)


2
C
->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)


2
D
->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)


2
E
->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)->(2,E)


2
E
->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)


2
D
->(1,B)->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)->(2,D)


1
C
->(1,C)


1
A
->(1,C)->(1,A)


1
B
->(1,C)->(1,A)->(1,B)


1
B
->(1,C)->(1,B)


1
A
->(1,C)->(1,B)->(1,A)


2
C
->(1,C)->(2,C)


2
D
->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)


2
E
->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,D)->(2,E)


2
E
->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)


2
D
->(1,C)->(2,C)->(2,E)->(2,D)



This has transformed an input of 6 rows to an output of 40 rows because there are so many permutations of paths through the data.
When you use DISTINCT then the query has to generate all the permutations and find the duplicates and throw them away. So it needs to wait until all the rows of the hierarchy are generated before it can return the first row and if there are many, many permutations of paths (which there will be for your sample data and join conditions - let alone having 2M rows of similar data) then it will be very, very slow.
What you can try to do is collapse the data so that each level of the hierarchy only connects to a single row and you do not need an OR condition in the hierarchy.
SELECT a.cust_num AS cust_num1,
       b.cust_num AS cust_num2,
FROM   table1 a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 b
       ON  a.cust_id  =  b.cust_id
       AND a.cust_num != b.cust_num

will join the table to itself and will also include the leaves of the hierarchy that do not connect to anything else; however, it will still generate duplicates and some leaves where there are branches at the same level and those duplicates and unnecessary leaves can be filtered using analytic functions:
SELECT cust_num1,
       cust_num2
FROM   (
  SELECT a.cust_num AS cust_num1,
         b.cust_num AS cust_num2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.cust_num, b.cust_num ORDER BY ROWNUM)
           AS rn,
         COUNT(b.cust_num) OVER (PARTITION BY a.cust_num) AS num_children
  FROM   table1 a
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 b
         ON  a.cust_id  =  b.cust_id
         AND a.cust_num != b.cust_num
)
WHERE  rn = 1
AND    (num_children = 0 OR cust_num2 IS NOT NULL)

Which outputs:



CUST_NUM1
CUST_NUM2




1
2


2
1



Then you can use that greatly simplified hierarchy to find the cust_num that are relevant and get the (unique) rows from the original table:
WITH connections (cust_num1, cust_num2) AS (
  SELECT cust_num1,
         cust_num2
  FROM   (
    SELECT a.cust_num AS cust_num1,
           b.cust_num AS cust_num2,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.cust_num, b.cust_num ORDER BY ROWNUM)
             AS rn,
           COUNT(b.cust_num) OVER (PARTITION BY a.cust_num) AS num_children
    FROM   table1 a
           LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 b
           ON  a.cust_id  =  b.cust_id
           AND a.cust_num != b.cust_num
  )
  WHERE  rn = 1
  AND    (num_children = 0 OR cust_num2 IS NOT NULL)
)
SELECT t.*
FROM   table1 t
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   connections c
         WHERE  t.cust_num = c.cust_num1
         START WITH
                c.cust_num1 = '1'
         CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                PRIOR c.cust_num2 = c.cust_num1
       )

Which outputs:



CUST_NUM
CUST_ID
TIER
STARTDATE
ENDDATE




1
A
X
1970-01-01 00:00:00.
1970-01-01 00:00:00.


1
B
Y
1970-01-01 00:00:00.
1970-01-01 00:00:00.


1
C
Z
1970-01-01 00:00:00.
1970-01-01 00:00:00.


2
C
X
1970-01-01 00:00:00.
1970-01-01 00:00:00.


2
D
Y
1970-01-01 00:00:00.
1970-01-01 00:00:00.


2
E
Z
1970-01-01 00:00:00.
1970-01-01 00:00:00.



For your sample data:
WITH connections (cust_num1, cust_num2) AS (
  SELECT cust_num1,
         cust_num2
  FROM   (
    SELECT a.cust_num AS cust_num1,
           b.cust_num AS cust_num2,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.cust_num, b.cust_num ORDER BY ROWNUM)
             AS rn,
           COUNT(b.cust_num) OVER (PARTITION BY a.cust_num) AS num_children
    FROM   table1 a
           LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 b
           ON  a.cust_id  =  b.cust_id
           AND a.cust_num != b.cust_num
  )
  WHERE  rn = 1
  AND    (num_children = 0 OR cust_num2 IS NOT NULL)
)
SELECT t.*
FROM   table1 t
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   connections c
         WHERE  t.cust_num = c.cust_num1
         START WITH
                c.cust_num1 = '2987530'
         CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                PRIOR c.cust_num2 = c.cust_num1
       )

Outputs:



CUST_NUM
CUST_ID
TIER
STARTDATE
ENDDATE




2819579
P000000000001924474
TIER_A
2015-09-24 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


2819579
P000000000001924474
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-01-29 00:00:00.


2819579
P000000000001924474
TIER_C
2019-01-29 00:00:00.
2021-04-13 11:15:00.


2819579
P000000000001763124
TIER_C
2022-03-17 11:00:00.
2022-09-14 00:00:00.


2987530
P000000000002057322
TIER_A
2016-05-14 00:00:00.
2016-07-15 00:00:00.


2987530
P000000000001634343
TIER_A
2017-03-24 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


2987530
P000000000001634343
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-02-14 00:00:00.


2987530
P000000000001634343
TIER_C
2019-02-14 00:00:00.
2021-06-16 00:00:00.


2987530
P000000000001711763
TIER_C
2022-02-07 12:45:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


2987595
P000000000002023001
TIER_A
2016-08-27 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


2987595
P000000000002023001
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-01-31 00:00:00.


2987595
P000000000002023001
TIER_C
2019-01-31 00:00:00.
2023-11-20 11:45:00.


2987595
P000000000001968900
TIER_C
2024-01-31 09:45:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


2987637
P000000000001745445
TIER_A
2017-04-17 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


2987637
P000000000001745445
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-02-23 00:00:00.


2987637
P000000000001745445
TIER_C
2019-02-23 00:00:00.
2023-11-01 13:00:00.


2987637
P000000000002023001
TIER_C
2023-11-20 11:45:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


2880699
P000000000002057322
TIER_A
2016-07-15 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


2880699
P000000000002057322
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-02-11 00:00:00.


2880699
P000000000002057322
TIER_C
2019-02-11 00:00:00.
2021-02-05 11:00:00.


2880699
P000000000001696121
TIER_C
2021-04-02 11:45:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


3535914
P000000000001711763
TIER_A
2016-09-17 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


3535914
P000000000001711763
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-02-23 00:00:00.


3535914
P000000000001711763
TIER_C
2019-02-23 00:00:00.
2022-02-07 12:45:00.


3535914
P000000000001743922
TIER_C
2022-10-26 09:45:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


3535924
P000000000001743922
TIER_A
2016-11-19 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


3535924
P000000000001743922
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-01-30 00:00:00.


3535924
P000000000001743922
TIER_C
2019-01-30 00:00:00.
2020-08-17 14:00:00.


3535924
P000000000001705747
TIER_C
2022-01-26 10:00:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


3136624
P000000000001832530
TIER_A
2016-02-13 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


3136624
P000000000001832530
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-02-14 00:00:00.


3136624
P000000000001832530
TIER_C
2019-02-14 00:00:00.
2021-01-13 09:30:00.


3136624
P000000000001743922
TIER_C
2021-10-05 00:00:00.
2022-10-26 09:45:00.


3136624
P000000000004969578
TIER_C
2023-11-02 10:15:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


2987781
P000000000001763124
TIER_A
2016-10-29 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


2987781
P000000000001763124
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-02-17 00:00:00.


2987781
P000000000001763124
TIER_C
2019-02-17 00:00:00.
2022-03-07 11:15:00.


2987781
P000000000001722432
TIER_C
2022-05-04 14:15:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


3754269
P000000000001722432
TIER_A
2017-09-16 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


3754269
P000000000001722432
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-02-11 00:00:00.


3754269
P000000000001722432
TIER_C
2019-02-11 00:00:00.
2022-04-04 13:45:00.


3754269
P000000000002035081
TIER_C
2022-05-20 13:30:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


3011204
P000000000001696121
TIER_A
2016-02-02 00:00:00.
2018-06-20 00:00:00.


3011204
P000000000001696121
TIER_B
2018-06-20 00:00:00.
2019-01-30 00:00:00.


3011204
P000000000001696121
TIER_C
2019-01-30 00:00:00.
2021-04-02 11:45:00.


3011204
P000000000001763124
TIER_C
2022-03-07 11:15:00.
2022-03-17 11:00:00.


3011204
P000000000001866100
TIER_C
2023-12-13 10:45:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.


3910271
P000000000002057322
TIER_C
2021-02-05 11:00:00.
2022-07-06 00:00:00.


3816264
P000000000001743922
TIER_C
2020-08-17 14:00:00.
2021-10-05 00:00:00.


3820058
P000000000001656589
TIER_A
2017-02-17 00:00:00.
2018-03-19 13:15:00.


3820058
P000000000001722432
TIER_C
2022-04-04 13:45:00.
2022-05-04 14:15:00.


3820058
P000000000001745445
TIER_C
2023-11-01 13:00:00.
2030-12-31 19:00:00.



fiddle

Your SQL has a number of issues:
SELECT DISTINCT CUST_NUM, CUST_ID, TIER, STARTDATE, ENDDATE
FROM TABLE1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR UPPER(CUST_NUM)=UPPER(CUST_NUM)
  OR PRIOR UPPER(CUST_ID)=UPPER(CUST_ID)
START WITH UPPER(CUST_NUM) = UPPER('2987530')
ORDER BY CUST_NUM, STARTDATE;

First and most importantly, you are using the same column value on both sides of the child-parent relationship (e.g. PRIOR cust_num = cust_num). This won't create a hierarchy - there needs to be a column that points to the parent's key, and that column cannot be the child's key.
Second, that OR clause in the CONNECT BY is going to cause grief. That means you have a data modeling problem whereby you have two potential keys and don't know which to use. OR in join clauses causes much mischief for execution plans, and presumably the same is true of CONNECT BY.
Thirdly, you are applying an UPPER function to the columns. This throws out any index use (unless you build a function-based index to match). Don't apply UPPER unless you have a clear need to do so. And if you find that you do, again, it points to a problem in the data model and/or programming that would allow inconsistent cases among matching keys.
Lastly, if CUST_NUM is actually numbers, you really should be use a number datatype for it, not a varchar2.
Beyond these general points, if I understand what you're trying to achieve, perhaps what you need is to do a normal join and then a connect by on the top of it. Something like this:
SELECT /*+ parallel(8) */ DISTINCT a.CUST_NUM, a.CUST_ID, a.TIER, a.STARTDATE, a.ENDDATE
  FROM table1 a,
       table1 b
 WHERE a.cust_id = b.cust_id
   AND a.cust_num != b.cust_num
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR a.cust_num = b.cust_num AND PRIOR a.cust_id != b.cust_id
  START WITH a.CUST_NUM = '2987530'
  ORDER BY CUST_NUM, STARTDATE;


@John, please see my edit (last paragraph) to see if that might help point in the right direction.

Paul, Thank you for the quick response. I agree with your comment on UPPER clause, the data is actually alphanumeric but i trimmed it down to just numeric in my example.
As for the other two comments, the data in the first 2 columns is relational w.r.t time.
Ex:
CUST_NUM 2987530 is tied to CUST_ID's P000000000002057322, P000000000001634343 and P000000000001711763.
CUST_ID P000000000002057322 is tied to CUST_NUM's 2987530, 2880699 and 3910271.
CUST_ID P000000000001711763 is tied to CUST_NUM's 2987530 and 3535914.
For these CUST_NUM's I have to find the associated CUST_ID's and so on..

I tried your suggestion and it is still taking time... been 5+ mins with no results yet

@John, my suggestion was to correct the logical error in your query. Dealing with a performance problem is another issue. Again, only by examining wait-based data like ASH and plan monitoring can you determine what your query is spending time on. When I tested using your example data I saw a massive amount of internal product that you hide at the end with the DISTINCT. So it's really a data model issue - this id-to-num-to-id-to-num simply creates too many snowflaked results even from the tiny data sample you provided. It's repeated many-to-many-to-many join. That's never going to perform.

Paul, I agree with you and really appreciate your feedback. I am stuck with this type of data and trying to find a solution.
Your comment "this id-to-num-to-id-to-num simply creates too many snowflaked results" is exactly the problem I am seeking a solution for

@John, I made an edit to my suggested SQL (added some != clauses to weed out self-joins), see if that helps any.

"This won't create a hierarchy" I think it will. (Also, your final query will not work in the edge-case when the initial cust_num set does not have a matching cust_id to another set of cust_num values and may exclude leaves of the hierarchy that do not have back edges to an ancestor).

I did try to fix your query - you can get a lot closer to the expected output changing from an INNER JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN but it still is not totally correct fiddle

@MT0, thanks MT0, you seem to have an enormous amount of time and patience to work these at a depth I simply cannot afford to invest given all my other duties at work. Thank you for all you do on this forum.
